# Get currency of today from ECB - pandassdmx?

Tags: pandas, sdmx

I need to get the latest currency rates from ECB for USD/EUR and CHF/EUR.
What is the recommended method?

Version 1:
Tried pandasdmx but do not know the most efficient way to extract the value:

```
ecb = sdmx.Request("ECB")
parameters = {
    "startPeriod": "2021-12-29",
    "endPeriod": "2021-12-29",
}
data_response = ecb.data(
    resource_id="EXR",
    key={"CURRENCY": ["CHF", "USD"]},
    params=parameters,
)
```

How do I parse the data_response to get the values for USD and CHF?

Version 2:
An alternative way I found was to access

```
request_url = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"
```

Parsing the XML is easy but the first version seems to be the more updated one.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
data = data_response.to_pandas()
data
```

to get the results as a Pandas Series:

```
FREQ  CURRENCY  CURRENCY_DENOM  EXR_TYPE  EXR_SUFFIX  TIME_PERIOD
D     CHF       EUR             SP00      A           2021-12-29     1.0380
      USD       EUR             SP00      A           2021-12-29     1.1303
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

The values of the `data` Series are the two exchange rates you are after. All the previous fields are part of a multi-index so to get a CHF you can use

```
data[('D', 'CHF', 'EUR', 'SP00', 'A', '2021-12-29')]
```

this will return

```
1.038
```

or you can use `.iloc`

```
data.iloc[0]
```

for CHF, `data.iloc[1]` for USD